# How to fix a 403 forbidden response when Fiddler is open

Tags: browser, fiddler, http-status-code-403

I am having issues trying to see the request made from my browser when I am navigating the site with Fiddler open (and the Decrypt HTTPS traffic option enabled). It seems that when I have Fiddler open I am receiving a 403 Response, but if I don't have fiddler open (or the Decrypt HTTPS traffic disabled) I don't receive the same behavior. Could someone please explain to me what may be happening and/or other possible debugging routes I could look into?

I was hoping to be able to navigate through the site with C# code (eventually add items to my cart all through code).

Comment: You should probably clarify whether the site is actually HTTPs, what the response code is when not using Fiddler, and also what URL you are testing against.